# How to draw a rectangle in C# using a mouse

Tags: c#-3.0, mouse, drawrectangle

I want to draw a rectangle on a form in C#. I read and found this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162493(v=VS.85).aspx). Are there any samples or tutorials available ? The article was not very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked appears to be C++, which may explain why it didn't help you much.

If you create events for MouseDown and MouseUp, you should have the two corner points you need for a rectangle.  From there, it's a matter of drawing on the form.  System.Drawing.* should probably be your first stop.  There are a couple of tutorials linked below:

[Drawing with Graphics in WinForms using C#](http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/graphics/winforms-drawing-cs.aspx)

[Draw a rectangle using Winforms (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529567/draw-a-rectangle-using-winforms)

[Graphics Programming using C#](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/1435391/Graphics-Programming-Using-C.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need this 3 functions and variables:

```
    private Graphics g;
    Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Blue, 2F);
    private Rectangle rectangle;
    private int posX, posY, width, height;
```

Second you need to make a mouse down event:

```
    private void pictureCrop_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            posX = e.X;
            posY = e.Y;
        }
    }
```

Third, you need to implemente the mouse up event:

```
    private void pictureCrop_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
            return;

        if (e.X > posX && e.Y > posY) // top left to bottom right
        {
            width = Math.Abs(e.X - posX);
            height = Math.Abs(e.Y - posY);
        }
        else if (e.X < posX && e.Y < posY) // bottom right to top left
        {
            width = Math.Abs(posX - e.X);
            height = Math.Abs(posY - e.Y);

            posX = e.X;
            posY = e.Y;
        }
        else if (e.X < posX && e.Y > posY) // top right to bottom left
        {
            width = Math.Abs(posX - e.X);
            height = Math.Abs(posY - e.Y);

            posX = e.X;
        }
        else if (e.X > posX && e.Y < posY) // bottom left to top right
        {
            width = Math.Abs(posX - e.X);
            height = Math.Abs(posY - e.Y);

            posY = e.Y;
        }

        g.DrawImage(_bitmap, 0, 0);
        rectangle = new Rectangle(posX, posY, width, height);
        g = pictureCrop.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);
    }
```

And to ensure that when you resize or move the form the rectangle will be there:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Graphics graph = e.Graphics;
        graph.DrawImage(_bitmap, 0, 0);
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(posX, posY, width, height);
        graph.DrawRectangle(pen, rec);
    }
```